# Postgresql Replication stopped unexpectedly Slave server's service is not starting. How can I Resume replication?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.5

Postgres Replication was working fine with Postgresql version 9.5.
when the template of a DB with 10gb of data was created and then the slave server stopped. Its Postgres service is not starting now. Can you suggest how to reconfigure the replication?
I had tried to reinstall and did the same procedure of replication but the service was not running after copying the data folder from the master server except the conf files.
These are the steps I followed:
In Master:-

```
*C:\Programfiles\PostgreSql\9.5\data\postgresql.conf
Modifications:
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 1
wal_keep_segments = 5
* C:\Programfiles\PostgreSql\9.5\data\pg_hba.conf
    Add:                                
host    replication     postgres        x.x.x.x/32         trust
```

In Slave:

```
'*C:\Programfiles\PostgreSql\9.5\data\postgresql.conf'
    'hot_standby = on'
```

Then create a file called recovery.conf under the path

```
‘C:\Programfiles\PostgreSql\9.5\data\’  and add:'
'standby_mode = 'on'
'primary_conninfo = 'host=x.x.x.x port=5432  user=postgres'  
'password=*****''
'trigger_file = 'E:\replication\trigger.txt'
```

In Master:
  Start the Postgresql Service.
    Open Sql Shell(psql) type the command

```
select pg_start_backup('base backup');
```

Then copy all the contents of data directory excluding postmaster.pid, and all configuration files(.conf) to Slave system’s data directory
Now type the command

```
select pg_stop_backup();
```

Kindly suggest a method to resume this replication.

This is the error log

```
2018-07-30 15:26:57 +04 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-07-30 15:26:57 +04 LOG:  database system was interrupted while in 
recovery at log time 2018-07-07 12:21:38 +04
2018-07-30 15:26:57 +04 HINT:  If this has occurred more than once some data 
might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.
2018-07-30 15:26:58 +04 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-07-30 15:26:59 +04 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-07-30 15:27:00 +04 FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2018-07-30 15:27:00 +04 LOG:  entering standby mode
2018-07-30 15:27:00 +04 LOG:  redo starts at 6F/5B387B70
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 
6F/5BD384F0
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 WARNING:  page 4 of relation base/16394/27254 does 
not exist
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 CONTEXT:  xlog redo Heap2/VISIBLE: cutoff xid 0
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 PANIC:  WAL contains references to invalid pages
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 CONTEXT:  xlog redo Heap2/VISIBLE: cutoff xid 0
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only 
connections
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 FATAL:  role "WIN-6QQN9PM6AUG$" does not exist
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 LOG:  startup process (PID 2808) was terminated by         
exception 0xC0000409
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 HINT:  See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a 
description of the hexadecimal value.
2018-07-30 15:27:01 +04 LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
```

Comment: Please suggest a method @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: "and then the slave server stopped" .. can you please be more descriptive in what the actual error is? Messages from the log for example?

Comment: Maybe the standby fell behind, and the primary has already removed the information. Look into the log.

Comment: @ThomasBerger I had added the error log. Please check

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Please see the error log above

Comment: Don't know what happened to your standby, but I think the only way forward from there is to wipe the standby and run a new `pg_basebackup`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you give the steps and code to do basebackup in windows.

Comment: No, that's too much for a SO answer. Read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-SETUP), which is pretty clear.

Comment: Oh, that sounds like a defect memory. Can you run a memtest on that system?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I had did pg_basebackup and tried to start postgres service it still not starting. Is there any other way?

Comment: If the normal way is too complicated for you, stop the primary and copy the data directory. *Not starting* doesn't say much. Maybe you could use Linux or some other simple operating system?